# How do I see the full dynamic range RAWs capture?

Tags: lightroom, raw, lightroom-5

RAW files capture a higher dynamic range than JPEGs, like [13EV](http://www.dxomark.com/Cameras/Sony/NEX-5R) (in the best case) for my Sony NEX-5R.

This lets me make more adjustments in post, but I have trouble visualizing what those adjustments would be. Is there a way for me to get Lightroom 5 to show me more of the data in the RAW file, so that I can realize that a particular adjustment would make sense for this photo?

For example, if Lightroom could do exposure fusion when I press and hold a button, I could see the full potential of the image, and realize that this photo would benefit from exposure fusion.

As another example, I can drag the exposure / shadows / highlights slider up and down, but I don't know at what point it stops showing me data in the RAW file and starts doing lossy math on the data, essentially synthesizing new information. I wish Lightroom had an exposure / shadows / highlights slider that stops short of synthesizing new information, and merely controls how the 13-bit EV RAW data is converted down to 8 bits.

I phrased this question in terms of dynamic range, but it really applies to getting Lightroom to show me any information captured in the RAW over the JPEG.

As I said, the problem I face is that I can take advantage of the extra information only if I foresee an adjustment I'd like to make, but I can't think of that adjustment without first seeing all the information in the photo.

What's the way out, other than experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic range is defined as the distance between the highlight clipping point and the noise floor. You can easily see where the highlight clipping point is in Lightroom by turning on the highlight clipping warning (the triangle in the top right corner of the histogram).

You can visualize the noise floor (the point where shadow details is lost to noise) by boosting the shadows until noise starts to dominate.

That's all you need to do to visualize the dynamic range you have to work with.

I don't know what you mean by *"what point it stops showing me data in the RAW file and starts doing lossy math on the data"*. The only thing in lightroom that does anything like "synthesizing new data" is the highlight recovery slider. Everything else is showing you real data from the RAW file, albeit with some mathematical manipulation (which is technically lossy although the data will be held internally at a higher bit depth minimising losses).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm aware of the highlight clipping warning, and the shadow clipping warning, too. I tried to clarify in the comments on Michael's answer. Do they help? Thanks, again.

Answer (score 6):

When you manipulate the tone curve of an image so that both the darkest shadow detail and the brightest highlight detail from a 14-bit RAW file that uses the full dynamic range available is visible at the same time on an 8-bit monitor it tends to "flatten" the image a little. Techniques such as *HDR*, *Exposure fusion*, using layers to set different exposure levels for various areas of an image are an attempt to increase local contrast in the image so that it still has some "pop" while preserving the detail in both the shadows and the highlights.

Depending on how you have LR set to display a RAW file when an image is first opened the 8-bits of information your monitor can display are usually taken from the middle of the full dynamic range. *Moving the exposure slider to the left doesn't synthesize new information that wasn't already present in the RAW file, it just shifts which range of values in the RAW data are depicted between black and white.* The value at which full saturation is displayed is increased, but so is the value that is rendered as full shadow (black). Moving the exposure slider in the other direction lowers the black point and white point so that details of shadows are made lighter at the same time dimmer highlights are displayed as full saturation (white). Sliding the highlights, shadows, or black sliders increase or decrease the exposure for only the pixels that fit that part of the luminance range in the image.

You can do the same thing with contrast, color temperature, saturation, etc. There is no way for an 8-bit monitor to simultaneously display all of the information contained in a 12- bit or 14-bit file. **When you move the sliders you aren't telling the program to synthesize something that isn't already in the RAW file, you are telling the program what parts of the information in the RAW file you wish it to display.**

Comment: So if I move the exposure slider all the way to the end, I'm seeing the top 8-bit slice of the 13-bit exposure range? Won't Lightroom at some point move past the 13-bit range of the RAW and end up having to multiply the pixels with a scale factor in order to make them brighter (closer to white)? Clearly this must be the case, because I can edit a JPEG in Lightroom, and increasing the exposure transforms an 8-bit image to another 8-bit image, rather than deciding what part of a 13-bit image to display. If I'm right, then I would like to know at what point LR starts "synthesizing" data.

Comment: To put it differently, let's say I shoot a scene in RAW and in JPEG. When I open the photos in Lightroom, I can move the sliders much more for the RAW file than I can for the JPEG, for the same loss of quality. Correct? Now, I wish Lightroom had a way to show me this delta. How far can I adjust exposure, shadows or highlights without resulting in noise or other artefacts created when LR multiplies the pixels by a scaling factor as opposed to merely showing me a different subset of the data in the RAW.

Comment: Thanks, again, Michael and Matt for putting up with my apparently hard to understand question and trying to help me out. One-click exposure compensation would be another example of helping me visualize the entire data in the RAW file.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi it's not as simple as lightroom just showing you different portions of the 14-bit RAW data as you adjust exposure comp, RAW data is linear, what lightroom shows you is "curved" to make it look more natural, so lightroom is "synthesising" data by multiplying pixel values all the time.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi ultimately at the end of the day the only way to reliably tell whether you have pushed exposure comp past the "end" of the RAW data is to use your eyes and look for the noise that is always present in the very bottom end of the RAW data.

Comment: Understood. Taking a step back from my (clearly wrong) example, is there a way for me to easily see the full potential of the RAW file, and realize that a particular adjustment would help? Thanks.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi I can't answer whether it would be easy for you or not, but learning how to read a histogram would be a start. Having a vision for what you want the shot to look like before you take it would be the long term goal. You then expose in such a way to allow for the realization of that vision.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi It's not so much that your questions are hard to understand. It is that they are hard to answer when they are constantly changing. Perhaps many users get tired of having to rewrite an answer multiple times to most of your questions. That and being told in one way or another that it isn't the answer you've already decided you want.

Comment: @MattGrum Even then he is seeing the noise floor that is included in the RAW data along with the signal when it was read from the sensor. At that point LR isn't synthesizing anything that is not there, it is just showing him the part that we usually want it to hide.

Comment: The "clearly this must be the case" in your first comment is not the case at all. It only seems to be clear to you because you don't understand that any RAW convertor (including the one that creates a JPEG in camera) doesn't use a linear response, but one that is curved at several points. But when you convert the RAW file to a JPEG in a very real sense what you are doing is discarding the data from the sensor readout that is currently not being used. Once you discard it you can't come back later and tell LR to now show that portion of the data.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, this question did not change at all (other than grammar) after it was posted. Even the others, I'd argue, did not change -- I left out some information that seemed obvious or irrelevant, but added it when it turned out to be relevant, or to address people's answers to what they thought I was asking rather than what I intended to ask. But we've had that discussion before, so let's not repeat it.

Comment: I take your point about the histogram and having a vision for a shot before taking it. Thanks.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi the best way of seeing whether a particular adjustment would help is by making that adjustment, then toggling it on and off to see if you think the overall result is improved. The best thing I can suggest is just to process a lot of RAW files and you'll eventually get a feel for what things you should adjust.